# 'draw a border' or 'draw a boundary'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, usage

What's the variant more appropriate?

Are they both right and equal?

- Draw a border
- Draw a boundary

In the context, for instance:

"When we're talking about philosophy and psychology we have to..."

- draw the border between them
- draw the boundary between them

Comment: In that particular example (a metaphorical line between two subjects), I would use _boundary_. It's impossible to say _in general_ which one is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draw%20a%20line%20between%2Cdraw%20a%20border%20between%2Cdraw%20a%20boundary%20between&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20line%20between%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20border%20between%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20boundary%20between%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20line%20between%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20border%20between%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20boundary%20between%3B%2Cc0), the preferred idiomatic phrase is ***to draw a line between***

> Also, draw the line between. Define a limit between two groups,
> courses of action, or the like. For example,
>
> - Legally it's important to draw a line between private and public enterprises.
> - We'll have to draw the line between our department's different jurisdictions.
>
> This metaphorical idiom was first recorded in 1793. ([Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+a+line+between))

Comment: Yeap, I know about the "draw the line". Yet recently I came across these 2 variants in the different books and therefore I was confused a little bit. Thank you for the answer!